# The connection to the server rancher.xxx.xxx was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

I installed kubectl by using the following commands:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https 
$ curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
$ echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list 
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y kubectl
```

We have created a rancher HA cluster with the help of RKE and moved the configuration file to `.kube/config` but can't able to use the kubectl. Please help me on these issue.

Answer (score 0):

While using kubeadm init you should perform those steps in order to use kubectl:

```
  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

As per rancher documentation:

> "Installing and Configuring kubectl" [here](http://here:https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/faq/kubectl/),
>   "Accessing Rancher Launched Kubernetes clusters without Rancher server running" [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/kubeconfig/),
>   "Accessing Clusters with kubectl and a kubeconfig File" [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/kubectl/),

You can try `kubectl --kubeconfig <path to your kube_config_cluster.yml> version` where kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml is the file with credentials for kubectl and helm.